# How to subset columns in a dataframe based of elements in a binary vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, `df` with `n` columns. I also randomly generate a binary vector, `x` of size `n` as well.

Each element in the binary vector corresponds to a column in the dataframe. I need help coding a function that subsets the dataset based upon the elements in the binary vector (ie., if `x[i]=0`, then the `ith` column should not be included in a new dataframe, `df_new`. `Elif x[i]=1`, then the `ith` column should be included in the new dataframe, `df_new`.

I need help coding out the logic described above.

```
#create a binary feature/column vector
feature_set <- vector(mode="logical", length=4)
#loop over all the items:
for(i in 1:4){
    #for each item, replace it with 0 or 1
    feature_set[i] = sample(0:1, 1);
}
#dataset with 4 features/columns
data.frame(X1 = rnorm(100),X2 = rnorm(100),X3 = rnorm(100),X4 = rnorm(100))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just `df[!!feature_set]`? But why not sample TRUE/FALSE directly?

Comment: here's one way:
`keep <- which(rbinom(4, 1, .5) == 1) df2 <- df[ , keep]`

Comment: @Sotos  Thank you for the comment, the problem was resolved by sampling TRUE/FALSE directly. On another note, what is the difference between the operation df[feature_set] and df[!!feature_set]?

Comment: Let me add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sampling `0` & `1`, then you need to convert them to logical before you use them for subseting your data frame. The way to do it is by adding leading `!!`, i.e.

```
!!c(0, 1, 0, 1)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

So to apply to a data frame to filter,

```
df[!!feature_set]
```

However, you can sample a logical vector directly, i.e.

```
i1 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 4, replace = TRUE)
i1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

#Use i1 to subset,

df[i1]
```